# Comparison string in jinja

Tags: comparison, jinja2

how to compare the data from database to compare with value in html with jinja?

I try gender value from db is Male

```
                {% set gender=user.gender  %}
                {% if gender == 'Male' %}
                {%  set check = "checked"  %}
                {% else %}
                {%  set check = "unchecked"  %}
                {% endif %}
```

but the output is Male `unchecked` and Female also `unchecked`

Comment: The logic for your code is correct. Have you checked your variables `user`, and is it possible that the "Male" you passed is in lowercase?

Comment: Yeah, user gender value is 'Male'. The user value is from an ontology and the datatype is string. But in jinja how to check datatype?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the issue so it probably means your user variable is not defined as you expect:

```
import jinja2
t=jinja2.Template('''         {% set gender=user.gender  %}
                {% if gender == 'Male' %}
                {%  set check = "checked"  %}
                {% else %}
                {%  set check = "unchecked"  %}
                {% endif %}
''')
for gender in ['Male', 'Female']:
    m = t.make_module(vars = {'user': {'gender': gender }})
    print(m.check)
```

prints:

```
checked
unchecked
```